# Performance of iteration over list of Pandas' dataframes varying wildly

Tags: python, pandas

Context: I am building a stock trading strategy backtester. I have 2446 CSVs containing OHLCV data. Each CSV is one trading day of data. I also concatenated these files into a single CSV of approximately 1.4 million rows after performance became a concern. More on that later.

In the early stages of development, I was reading each file one at a time with pd.read_csv and appending each dataframe to a list. Then I would run the simulation on the list of dataframes. Using this technique, **just the simulation itself** takes ~97 seconds.

```
all_days = []
for file in (os.listdir("C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/EURUSD/CSV")):
   all_days.append(pd.read_csv("C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/EURUSD/CSV/"+file))
```

I wanted the entire program to run faster. So I created a single CSV, and used groupby to separate each day of data. Sure enough, the creation of the list of dataframes is much quicker. But here's where I'm getting thrown for a loop: The simulation has slowed down appreciably. The simulation now takes ~172 seconds **even though it is still receiving a list of dataframes just as before**. It is also worth noting that the simulation produces the exact same result.

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/EURUSD/Concatenated CSVs/EURUSD.csv", 
index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

all_days = []
for each in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='D')):
    if each[1].empty is False:
        all_days.append(each[1])
```

What factors could be causing performance to degrade so much?

Comment: Ok I think I may be on to something. Within the for loop in the second block of code, resetting the index of the dataframe before appending to a list reduced simulation execution time from ~172 seconds to ~82 seconds. Would love to hear from a Pandas expert on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect that to be faster?

You're saving some overhead in not having to open each file individually, but you're ultimately still reading the exact same amount of data into memory.

In the second example though, you're asking pandas to make a smaller dataframe by scanning all 1.4 million rows of data!

Try timing how long your second example spends constructing the dataframe, and how long it spends iterating over it.

Comment: To clarify, I only want to know why **the simulation** code is slower despite the fact that I have not made any modifications to it. The creation of the list of dataframes is definitely faster.